# Как разрешить не разрешимые зависимости npm?

Tags: node.js, angular2, npm

Допустим есть рабочее приложение в которое мы хотим добавить новый функционал. Для добавления нового функционала нам необходимо установить некоторые пакеты из npm. При установке нового пакета возникают проблемы, которые указаны в консоле. 
Так вот вопрос в том, что если пытаться делать так как написано в консоле, то возникают конфликты с другими пакетами. Исходя из правил semver.org у большинства пакетов чаще всего меняются последние 2 цифры, при этом, как написано в документации ничего не должно ломаться, но конфликт возникает. Как решать такие проблемы? Как вы разрешаете конфликт с зависимостями в npm?

Наглядный пример:

```
├─┬ angular2-universal@2.1.0-rc.1
│ └── xhr2@0.1.4
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.2
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.7.4


npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.1.27 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-universal@2.1.0-rc.1 requires a peer of zone.js@~0.6.21 but none was installed.
```

---

```
{
      "name": "ddddd",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "license": "MIT",
      "angular-cli": {},
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
        "test": "ng test",
        "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
        "e2e": "protractor"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
        "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
        "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
        "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
        "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
        "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.27",
        "angular2-universal": "^2.1.0-rc.1",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "jquery": "^3.1.1",
        "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16",
        "ng2-file-upload": "^1.1.4-2",
        "rxjs": "^5.0.2",
        "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
        "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
        "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
        "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
        "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
        "karma": "1.2.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
        "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
        "protractor": "~4.0.13",
        "ts-node": "1.2.1",
        "tslint": "^4.0.2",
        "typescript": "~2.0.3"
      }
    }
```

Comment: добавьте полный package.json в вопрос

Comment: @MikhailVaysman добавил.